# Insert Multiple rows record Codeignite

Tags: php

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: stock
>
> Filename: controllers/stock.php
>
> Line Number: 28
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\pharmacy\application\controllers\stock.php Line:
>   28 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\pharmacy\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   `require_once`

----this is my code----

```
public function save_stock($stock)
        {

                $supplier_name  =$this->input->post('cmb_supplier');
                $purchase_date  =$this->input->post('Txtdate');
                $invoice_number =$this->input->post('txtnumber');
                $med_name       =$this->input->post('product');
                $expiry_date    =$this->input->post('expiry');
                $qty            =$this->input->post('qty');
                $price          =$this->input->post('price');
                $cgst           =$this->input->post('tax_amount');
                $grand_total    =$this->input->post('total_amount');


            foreach ($supplier_name as $index => $supplier_name) 
            {

                $supplier_name  =$supplier_name[$index];
                $purchase_date  =$purchase_date[$index];
                $invoice_number =$invoice_number[$index];
                $med_name       =$med_name[$index];
                $expiry_date    =$expiry_date[$index];
                $qty            =$qty[$index];
                $price          =$price[$index];
                $cgst           =$cgst[$index];
                $grand_total    =$grand_total[$index];

                    $stock[] = array(
                            'supplier_name'     =>$supplier_name,
                            'purchase_date'     =>$purchase_date,
                            'invoice_number'    =>$invoice_number,
                            'med_name'          =>$med_name,
                            'expiry_date'       =>$expiry_date,
                            'qty'               =>$qty,
                            'price'             =>$price,
                            'cgst'              =>$cgst,
                            'grand_total'       =>$grand_total
                    );
                    $this->db->insert("purchase_stock",$stock);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not define $stock as array out of the for loop. That is why you are getting the error.

Next, you need to user **insert_batch** instead of **insert** for multiple row inserts.

```
$stock = [];
foreach ($supplier_name as $index => $supplier_name) 
        {

            $supplier_name  =$supplier_name[$index];
            $purchase_date  =$purchase_date[$index];
            $invoice_number =$invoice_number[$index];
            $med_name       =$med_name[$index];
            $expiry_date    =$expiry_date[$index];
            $qty            =$qty[$index];
            $price          =$price[$index];
            $cgst           =$cgst[$index];
            $grand_total    =$grand_total[$index];

                $stock[] = array(
                        'supplier_name'     =>$supplier_name,
                        'purchase_date'     =>$purchase_date,
                        'invoice_number'    =>$invoice_number,
                        'med_name'          =>$med_name,
                        'expiry_date'       =>$expiry_date,
                        'qty'               =>$qty,
                        'price'             =>$price,
                        'cgst'              =>$cgst,
                        'grand_total'       =>$grand_total
                );
                $this->db->insert_batch("purchase_stock",$stock);
        }
```

Comment: This is my controller code
public function save_stock()
  {
   $this->st_model->save_stock();
   
  }